# How can i remove the old soure folder display after changing Source Folder

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

> Initially my project was developed with `src` as the *default source*
>
> Now I changed the source folder to `src/main/java`. But the `src`
>   folder is displayed in the project explorer.   How can i remove that.

[image: Image of my project explorer]

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the "scr" folder and say delete, but u need to add the new source folder location in "Sources" tab in "Build Path-> Configure Build Path" else your project cannot be built because of classpath error

Comment: deleting the src folder will delete all the files inside including src/main/java. So its not possible.

Comment: Let me clarify this, Are u creating a seperate "scr/main/java folder or are you adding "/main/java" to the existing src folder?

Comment: i created a new package. named `src.main.java`